# Check if objects are within a path

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a simple game with some moving dots. The player draws a closed shape around some of the moving dots and if all dots are of the same type, then there is a score to the player. The path is in points and stored into an arraylist. My question is, how do I check if there is objects within the path?

EDIT: Could it be done with Region class and the method inside(int x, int y) ??

Comment: The path being the line drawn by the player?

Comment: Yes, the line that the player draws.

Comment: a couple pictures would be a great addition

Comment: Look into flood-fill algorithms and go from there.

Comment: Is pictures really necessary!? Imagine a screen full av moving dots in different color. The move like bugs in all direction. The player draws a path like a circle and when the player lift the finger from screen, then shape is closed with a line segment from the last point to the first point. Then I want to check if there is any of the moving dots inside the path.

Answer (score 0):

Can the closed shape be any polygon or is it limited to a rectangle?  If it can be any polygon then this sounds like a [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) problem (but I'd have to dust off my algorithms book to tell you for sure).  If it is a convex hull problem then you should be able to solve this with a Jarvis march algorithm.

Also Wikipedia shows another option would be [Ray Casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).  A Java implementation of this algorithm can be found [here](http://www.ytechie.com/2009/08/determine-if-a-point-is-contained-within-a-polygon.html)

Comment: It could be any polygon shape.

Answer (score 0):

your going to have to draw a rectangle ..use the rectangle class and then use the point class to make your points.

i think this import can help you import android.graphics.Rect;

code something like this:

```
Rect myrectangleContainer=new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200);

Point dot= new Point(x,y);
```

then collect the boolean

```
boolean isDotWithRect=myrectangleContainer.contains(dot.x,dot.y)
```